# Is this a derivation of normal equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

I am reading a paper on real estate price prediction and it says the following...

> In OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) we estimate the model $y = B\beta + u$ where $y$ is the dependent variable $X$ is a matrix of the observations on the independent variables and $u$ is the error term.
> ...
>
> The regression coefficients $\beta$ are estimated by minimizing $(y - X\beta)'(y - X\beta)$

The first part makes sense, but the second part doesn't make sense to me. It looks like something close to normal equations, but I can't reproduce it.

Why do the coefficients come from minimizing that term?

Comment: Write it out:  it is just the sum of squares of the deviations from the linear model.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I wrote it out as $y^Ty - y^TX\beta - \beta^TX^Ty +\beta^TX^TX\beta$ and that didn't help me see anything. I must have gone wrong somewhere or I am still missing something

Comment: No no no.  The prime is *transpose*, so $(y - X\beta)^\prime (y - X \beta) = y^2 - \beta^2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

Comment: did I not transpose it and multiply it together correctly? Can you show how to get from the left side of your equation to the right side in an answer?

Comment: I did transpose and multiply it correctly, but IMO that is the long way to look at it. The easiest way for me to see it is to just view the stuff in the parentheses as the erros vector. Then $E^TE = \sum E^2$